# Filter by Freezed Generic Field

Tags: flutter, dart, freezed, flutter-freezed

I have a Freezed generated class with two factory constructors, both containing the same field that is a generic. Given a list of this class I would like to be able to filter based on the type that the field is.

Here is my class:

```dart
@freezed
sealed class Artifact<T extends Location> with _$Artifact<T> {
  const Artifact._();

  const factory Artifact.FromServer(
      {required String id,
      @_LocationConverter() required T location
}) = ServerArtifact<T>;

  const factory Artifact.NewArtifact({
    @_LocationConverter() required T location,
  }) = NewArtifact<T>;

  factory Artifact.fromJson(Map<String, Object?> json) =>
      ServerArtifact.fromJson(json);
}
```

My generic type Location is a Freezed union that can either be a point or a polygon.

With this class I can create new Artifacts like:

```dart
final newArtifact = Artifact.NewArtifact(
    location: Location.FromPoint(
      latitude: curLocation.latitude,
      longitude: curLocation.longitude,
    ),
  );
```

The problem with creating artifacts like this, is when I debugged my application it looks like Dart is storing the type of newArtifact as `_$NewArtifactImpl<Location>` -- even if I'm passing in a `Location.fromPoint()` (which returns as `PointLocation` class that extends Location). So if I add `newArtifact` to a list I am unable to filter using the `whereType<Artifact<PointLocation>>()`. To get around this I made my own custom filter as shown below:

```dart
List<Artifact<PointLocation>> get pointArtifacts => artifacts
    .where((a) => a.location is PointLocation)
    .map<Artifact<PointLocation>>((a) => a as Artifact<PointLocation>)
    .toList();
```

However, when this runs I get the error:

> type '_$NewArtifactImpl' is not a subtype of type 'Artifact' in type cast

I would not only like to filter to get artifacts with a PointLocation, but also be able to be able to narrow the type of Artifact to Artifact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an `Artifact` by using the typical Freezed factory constructor without explicitly setting generics I was able to create my artifact as follows:

```dart
final newArtifact = Artifact<PointLocation>.NewArtifact(
  title: title,
  description: description,
  location: PointLocation(
    latitude: curLocation.latitude,
    longitude: curLocation.longitude,
  ),
);
```

Which then allowed me to use the `whereType` array filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You have a [generic](https://dart.dev/language/generics) [Freezed class](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed#creating-a-model-using-freezed) `Artifact<T>` where `T` extends `Location`, and you are trying to filter a list of `Artifact` instances by the specific type of `Location` they hold, e.g., `PointLocation`.

[Unlike Java](https://dart.dev/language/generics#generic-collections-and-the-types-they-contain), Dart does retain type information for generics at runtime due to its reified generics.

It means your issue with filtering and casting Freezed classes does not come from Dart's handling of generics, but rather from how Dart's type system handles *downcasting* generic types.
When you attempt to (down)cast `Artifact<Location>` to `Artifact<PointLocation>`, the Dart's type system cannot guarantee the type safety of this operation at compile time without explicit checks or conversions.

> ```
> type '_$NewArtifactImpl<Location>' is not a subtype of type 'Artifact<PointLocation>' in type cast
> ```

---

See "[Dart / Type system / Generic type assignment](https://dart.dev/language/type-system#generic-type-assignment)":

In the context of your `Artifact<Location>` and `Artifact<PointLocation>` scenario, Dart's type system allows you to assign a subtype to a supertype variable ([covariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Formal_definition)), mirroring the `List<MaineCoon>` to `List<Cat>` example from the documentation. That means you can assign a more specific list (`List<MaineCoon>`) to a broader list type (`List<Cat>`) without explicit casting.

[image: https://dart.dev/assets/img/language/type-hierarchy-generics.png]

However, assigning a supertype to a subtype variable (the reverse direction, analogous to assigning `List<Animal>` to `List<Cat>`) is not allowed by Dart's static analysis because it introduces the possibility of runtime type errors.

That is what is meant by "implicit downcast," which Dart disallows for non-dynamic types to make sure type safety. The documentation confirms that to perform such an assignment, an explicit cast is required (`myAnimals as List<Cat>`), though this cast can fail at runtime if `myAnimals` does not actually contain `Cat` instances.

In the case of your Freezed class `Artifact<T>`, when trying to downcast from `Artifact<Location>` to `Artifact<PointLocation>`, Dart's type system treats this similarly to the `List<Animal>` to `List<Cat>` casting scenario. Even though Dart's generics are reified and retain type information at runtime, allowing for runtime type checks (e.g., using `is` checks), the static type system prevents implicit downcasting to make sure type safety.

That means that while you can check at runtime if an `Artifact`'s `location` is a `PointLocation` using `is`, statically assigning `Artifact<Location>` to `Artifact<PointLocation>` without an explicit cast is disallowed because it could lead to type errors at runtime if the actual `location` is not a `PointLocation`.

---

You might need to focus on safely handling the instances based on their actual runtime types, as Dart allows for runtime type checking of generic types. For filtering and transforming a list of `Artifact<Location>` to `Artifact<PointLocation>`, consider using runtime checks for both the artifact and its location, while avoiding unsafe downcasting:

```dart
List<Artifact<PointLocation>> get pointArtifacts {
  return artifacts.where((artifact) => artifact.location is PointLocation).map((artifact) {
    // That check is safe due to Dart's reified generics, making sure `location` is indeed a PointLocation.
    final PointLocation pointLocation = artifact.location as PointLocation;
    // Use a factory constructor or a method to safely convert or recreate
    // the artifact with a PointLocation, making sure type safety.
    return Artifact<PointLocation>.fromServer(
      id: artifact.id,
      location: pointLocation,
    );
  }).toList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your in-depth answer! Due to me having many artifacts, I wanted to avoid instantiating a new Artifact each time I want to retrieve a list of artifacts, however your explanation of how Dart doesn't immediately infer lowest type (which coming from Typescript surprised me) helped me come up with a solution that I will post below.

Comment: @Gabe Great, well done, and upvoted.